# Flushing newest parameters from ReportViewer control to the ServerReport from code

Tags: c#, report-viewer2010

After a user edits report parameters, at some point I try to access new parameters with

```
_reportViewer.ServerReport.GetParameters()
```

Since that gives only the parameters user has submitted to the server with  click on the View Report button, I'm looking to:

a) Simulate click on a View Button from code or

b) Get those parameters in some other way, preferably one that doesn't involve reflection.

How could I "flush" the current parameters from the automatically generated report control from code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `ReportViewer1.ServerReport.GetParameters()` from the `ReportViewer1` `UnLoad` event you will get the values the client entered.

ASP.NET:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" 
                            runat="server" 
                            ProcessingMode="Remote" 
                            AsyncRendering="true" 
                            EnableViewState="true" 
                            OnUnload="ReportViewer1_Unload">
```

Codebehind:

```
    protected void ReportViewer1_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportParameterInfoCollection ParameterCollection = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.GetParameters();
    }
```